# how to make a list that has different time attached to each object?

Tags: python, list, clock

```
1 chaviv     22 : 00
2 osher      22 : 13
3 sukar      22 : 26
4 neria      22 : 39
5 negosa     22 : 52
6 shlomy     23 : 5
7 itamar     23 : 18
8 sagie      23 : 31
9 zarfati    23 : 44
10 nitzan    23 : 57
11 daniel    24 : 10
12 motty     24 : 23
13 sukar     24 : 36
14 shoham    24 : 49
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write it like this. First we import the datetime object and timedelta which will be used to make the initial time point and then to add 13 minutes to it, in order to print the desired output. After this we iterate over the list of names, while keeping the index, thanks to `enumerate()` then each time point is printed along with the index and the name and we shift the time point 13 minutes ahead.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

names = ['chaviv', 'osher', 'sukar', 'neria', 'negosa', 'shlomy', 'itamar', 'sagie',
'zarfati', 'nitzan', 'daniel', 'motty', 'sukar', 'shoham'] # list of names.

time_point = datetime(1, 1, 1, 22, 00, 00) # We start at 22:00.

for i, name in enumerate(names, 1): # The index starts at 1
    print(f'{i} {name} \t {time_point.strftime("%H:%M")}') # The index, name, time_point are printed.
    time_point += timedelta(minutes = 13) # The timepoint is adjusted to be 13 mins ahead.
```

Output:

```
1 chaviv     22:00
2 osher      22:13
3 sukar      22:26
4 neria      22:39
5 negosa     22:52
6 shlomy     23:05
7 itamar     23:18
8 sagie      23:31
9 zarfati    23:44
10 nitzan    23:57
11 daniel    00:10
12 motty     00:23
13 sukar     00:36
14 shoham    00:49
```